# Extra Space on Essential Grid

Tags: css, screen-size, margins

I am using essential grid to show 4 panels on my homepage. the panels work fine on desktop however on mobile there is extra margin at the top. I have applied following CSS;

```
.l-section{    margin-top: 0 !Important;
    min-height: 0 !Important;
}
```

But nothing seem to work. The website is [tyloz.com](http://www.tyloz.com/), any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your homepage, you'll wanna add this media-query.

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .l-subsection-h {
        margin-top: 0!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much.